# Why am I getting a run time error(SIGSEGV) for the following code?

Tags: c

This is the solution of the Prime Generator problem on SPOJ(Sphere online judge), I have checked and no array is out of bound, and still it is showing run time error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    int i,j,a,b;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(n){
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        int arr[b];

        // Filling the array
        for(i=2;i<=b;i++){
            arr[i-2]=i;
        }

        int p,c;
        for(p=0;p<b-1;p++){
            if(arr[p]){
                if(arr[p]>=a){
                    printf("\n%d", arr[p]); 
                }
                for(c=p+arr[p];c<b-2;c+= arr[p]){
                    arr[c]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        n--;    
    }
```

Comment: The prime generator problem statement reads: "In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000)". That means the size of your `arr` variable can go up to 4GB in size. See any problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with this declaration:

```
int arr[b];
```

This attempts to allocate 4·*b* bytes of memory on the stack. Stack size is usually limited to a couple megabytes of memory, but for the larger test cases, the judging tool is going to invoke your program with *b* = 1000000000 which causes your program to allocate 4 gigabytes of memory on the stack. This is more than you can place on the stack, causing the SIGSEGV you observe.

To resolve the issue, use `malloc()` to allocate `arr` instead of declaring a variable length array. Memory allocated via `malloc()` comes from the *heap* which can grow as large as the operating system lets you, usually until all the memory is exhausted and possibly further.

You should also consider to implement a different algorithm to solve this problem. There are primality tests that are much more efficient than the naïve sieve of Eratosthenes you implement.